# Passing json from db to blade template

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-controller

Let say I have ["gravy1", "gravy2"] in table's column "gravy". How can I display it so I can get this result: [image: this result]

This is my controller:

```
$grav = DB::table('items')
->select('gravy')
->get();
$gravies = json_decode($grav);

return view('welcome', [
    'gravies' => $gravies,
    ]);
```

Comment: Basically you can just use a loop for each of the array's value inside your view.